# How to Store AlphaColor to Database Field through LiveBindings

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, livebindings

I am trying to store the `ComboColorBox.Color` property in a database field through LiveBindings in a Firemonkey Project. I want to store the hexadecimal `AlphaColor` value, but the hex color value is automatically converted to a decimal value and not an `AlphaColor`.

I've searching in the LiveBindings documentation and found that I can change the value of control property before is stored in database writing a binding expression in `CustomParse` property of the Binding. The problem is that there is no built in function to convert an `AlphaColor` to a `String` in an expression.

Do I have to write a custom function to do that? How do I write that function and where? Or there is another solution?

Comment: There's an example of using color values with livebindings, here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Tutorial:_Using_TPrototypeBindSource_and_the_LiveBindings_Designer

Answer (score 1):

You should know that a `TAlphaColor` is an integer, or more precisley a `cardinal` as defined in `System.UITypes`

```
type TAlphaColor = Cardinal;
```

Thus you can apply any integer to string conversion functions, like:

```
Label1.Text := IntToStr((Sender as TComboColorBox).Color);    // decimal notation
Label2.Text := IntToHex((Sender as TComboColorBox).Color, 8); // hexadecimal notation
```

So, to store the `TAlphaColor` value as a hexadecimal string, you would convert the color value using `IntToHex()`. On the other hand, Are you sure you really want to store it in the db as a string in the first place.